# Search iOS photos by keyword?

Tags: ios, react-native, search, photo, photokit

Apple's Photos app allows users to query photos with search keywords like "surfing", "food", "sky".

How could a third-party iOS app with Camera and Photos permissions search the phone's camera roll using arbitrary strings?

[Searching for Photos is part of the SiriKit API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/photos/searching_for_photos). Could we pass strings as a possible approach or is there a better way?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I could not find a way even after longer research. But the good news is that you can use the exact same neural network used to achieve the results in the photo app to build your own search index. Here is some sample code:

```
let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()           
let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: fetchOptions)
fetchResult.enumerateObjects { asset, index, pointer in
    self.assetManager.requestImage(for: asset,
                                   targetSize: CGSize(width: 150, height: 100), 
                                   contentMode: .aspectFit, 
                                   options: .none) { image, metadata in
            if let uiImage = image, let cgImage = uiImage.cgImage {
                let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage)
                let request = VNClassifyImageRequest()
                try? requestHandler.perform([request])
                let results = request.results as! [VNClassificationObservation]
                // Filter the 1303 classification results, and use them in your app
                // in my case, fullfill promise with a wrapper object
                promise(.success(ClassifiedImage(imageIdentifier: asset.localIdentifier,
                                classifications: results.filter { $0.hasMinimumPrecision(0.9, forRecall: 0.0) }.map{
                                    ($0.identifier, nil)
                                    })))
            }

        }
}
```

More info: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/222

Also note: When building a search index you can use the `localIdentifier` of class `PHAsset` when fetching the assets.